django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: users_user.username
I try to create a custom user model, and create a new simple user via the admin panel, but I can't do that, please check my code
This is my models.py file:
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin
from .managers import UserManager


class User(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # Personal information fields
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    # Permissions and status fields
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # Important dates fields
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

This is my managers.py file:
class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self.model(email=email, password=password, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_active", True)

        if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("Super User must be staffed"))
        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("Super User must be staffed"))

        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


and this is my admin.py file:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = User
    list_display = ("email", "is_active", "is_staff", "is_superuser")
    list_filter = ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')
    search_fields = ('name', "email")

    # Editing field sets
    fieldsets = (
        ("Personal", {"fields": ("email", "password")}),
        ("Permissions", {"fields": ("is_active", "is_staff", "is_superuser")}),
    )
    # Add a new user fieldsets
    add_fieldsets = (
        ("Personal", {"fields": ("email", "password1", "password2")}),
        ("Permissions", {"fields": ("is_active", "is_staff", "is_superuser")}),
    )


admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)

I tried to create a new user via the admin panel, but I have gotten this error
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: users_user.username

That message tells you that you already have a user registered in your database with the same name.

First of all you have created "CustomUserManager" but you use "UserManager" and also you don't need to inheritance from "PermissionsMixin"
Here is the Django AbstractUser:
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    An abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with
    admin-compliant permissions.

    Username and password are required. Other fields are optional.
    """

    username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

    username = models.CharField(
        _("username"),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_(
            "Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only."
    ),
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            "unique": _("A user with that username already exists."),
         },
    )

According to this, you cannot leave the username empty.
Here is a quick solution:
class User(AbstractUser):
    """User"""

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.username = self.email
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


If you don't want to use username field at all, Please remove it from your User model by adding username = None. Here is updated code.
class User(AbstractUser):
    # Remove username field from User model
    username = None

    # Personal information fields
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    # Permissions and status fields
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # Important dates fields
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

Please share your specific requirements or any issues you're encountering. This will help provide perfect solution.

is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True) can be removed from your model as AbstractUser already has this field with default=True.

is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) can also be removed from your model as AbstractUser already has this field with default=False

for created and modified fields you can also use
https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#timestampedmodel
